# Python and PCRE regex that are the same give different outputs for the same input

Tags: python, regex, pcre, pcre2

I am trying to implement the `minbpe` library in [zig](https://github.com/GoWind/tokenizig/blob/main/src/main.zig#L33), using a wrapper over [PCRE library](https://github.com/liyu1981/jstring.zig).

The pattern in Python is `r"""'(?:[sdmt]|ll|ve|re)| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+"""`

When I use the pattern with a UTF-8 encoded text like `abcdeparallel १२४`, I get the following output:

```
>>> import regex as re
>>> p = re.compile(r"""'(?:[sdmt]|ll|ve|re)| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+""")
>>> p
regex.Regex("'(?:[sdmt]|ll|ve|re)| ?\\p{L}+| ?\\p{N}+| ?[^\\s\\p{L}\\p{N}]+|\\s+(?!\\S)|\\s+", flags=regex.V0)
>>> p.findall("abcdeparallel १२४")
['abcdeparallel', ' १२४']
```

It looks like this is more or less the same in PCRE flavored regex as well, with me just having to add a `/g` flag in the end for UTF-8 matching

However when I try to use the pattern with pcre via the pcre2test tool on macOS, I get a much different output

```
$ pcre2test -8
PCRE2 version 10.42 2022-12-11
  re> /'(?:[sdmt]|ll|ve|re)| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+/g
data> abcdeparallel १२४
 0: abcdeparallel
 0:  \xe0
 0: \xa5\xa7
 0: \xe0
 0: \xa5\xa8
 0: \xe0
 0: \xa5
 0: \xaa
```

Somehow it looks like the code points for the Hindi numerals (1, 2 4) are interpreted differently and the output is matched as a totally different set of characters

```
>>> "\xe0\xa5\xa7\xe0\xa5\xa8"
'à¥§à¥¨'
```

Is there a flag or something that I am missing that must be passed to have the same behaviour as the the `regex` Package/module from Python ? When UTF-8 code points are decoded into bytes, wouldn't the library know how to put them back together into the same code points ?

Comment: Use the correct encoding. The results are given in UTF-8 bytes: `b"\xe0\xa5\xa7\xe0\xa5\xa8".deocode('utf-8')`

Comment: still don't understand why PCRE gives me 8 matches unlike the Python versions 2 matches.

Comment: As @sytech says, the output of PCRE is UTF-8 bytes.  Those 6 bytes when decoded become 2 characters, the same as Python.

Comment: Actually, in PCRE regex, you can use the UTF/UCP verbs, try adding them to the start of the regex pattern, `(*UTF)(*UCP)`

Comment: PCRE as is, is not processing it as UTF-8, but rather as an 8-bit encoding `"१२४".encode("utf-8").decode('latin-1')` would be `à¥§à¥¨à¥ª` and based on your regex pattern that would be segmented as `à|¥§|à|¥¨|à|¥|ª`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The Hindi codepoints are actually matched, but rendered on screen as UTF-8 hexcodes:

```
>>> "१२४".encode("utf-8")
b'\xe0\xa5\xa7\xe0\xa5\xa8\xe0\xa5\xaa'
```

According to the [pcr2test spec](https://www.pcre.org/current/doc/html/pcre2test.html#SEC17):

> When pcre2test is outputting text in the compiled version of a pattern, bytes other than 32-126 are always treated as non-printing characters and are therefore shown as hex escapes.

> When pcre2test is outputting text that is a matched part of a subject string, it behaves in the same way, unless a different locale has been set for the pattern (using the locale modifier). In this case, the isprint() function is used to distinguish printing and non-printing characters.

The spec doesn't mention which locales can be used. The example (fr_FR) suggests two-letter country code and two-letter language code, but it's unclear to me if Hindi is supported.

With the `(*UTF) flag you do get two matches and the Hindi numerals are  then rendered as unicode hexes:

```
re> /(*UTF)(?:[sdmt]|ll|ve|re)| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+/g
data> abcdeparallel १२४
 0: abcdeparallel
 0:  \x{967}\x{968}\x{96a}
```

Comment: This worked. Thanks :). I wonder why I need the `*UTF` prefix though, because \p{L} and \p{N} should match any unicode character or number anyway.

Answer (score 0):

You just need to decode the bytes using UTF-8, rather than treating them as a string.

```py
>>> "\xe0\xa5\xa7\xe0\xa5\xa8"
'à¥§à¥¨'
>>> b"\xe0\xa5\xa7\xe0\xa5\xa8".decode('utf-8')
'१२'
```

To get a result that looks more like the Python one, use the `utf8_input` option (with the 32-bit pcre2test) or `(*UTF)` in the beginning of the pattern:

```
$ pcre2test -32
PCRE2 version 10.42 2022-12-11
  re> /'(?:[sdmt]|ll|ve|re)| ?\p{L}+| ?\p{N}+| ?[^\s\p{L}\p{N}]+|\s+(?!\S)|\s+/g,utf8_input
data> abcdeparallel १२४
 0: abcdeparallel
 0:  \x{967}\x{968}\x{96a}
```

In Python, you can show these code points as follows:

```py
>>> u"\u0967\u0968\u096a"
'१२४'
```